# Appending images vertically in ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick

```
convert -append 1.jpg 2.jpg out.jpg
```

This command appends 1.jpg and 2.jpg horizontally. What is the command to do this vertically?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

For vertical stacking (top to bottom):

```
convert -append 1.jpg 2.jpg out.jpg
```

For horizontal stacking (left to right):

```
convert +append 1.jpg 2.jpg out.jpg
```

Comment: In new version +append is left to right

Comment: And what is "vertical" in the new version? :-)

Comment: http://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#append

Comment: as  @TrinhHoangNhu mentioned, now -append means vertical (probably due to the increased volume of vertical devices)

Answer (score 20):

Use **-append** to stack images **top-to-bottom**.

Use **+append** to stack images **left-to-right**.

Source: http://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#append

Answer (score 17):

For latest imagemagick from V7 , the following is command

```
magick input1.jpg input2.jpg -append out.jpg
```