# Generating a thumbnail reel from a video with image magik and/or ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, images, imagemagick

I [read a post](https://superuser.com/q/599348/531787) detailing how you can call ffmpeg from image magik. I want to learn how to:

1. Take a series of screenshots from a video,
2. store them in memory (dont' write all images to disk)
3. at the end of the video concat all the images and persist a single image to disk.

[This](https://i.ytimg.com/sb/3mbkTGTafgM/storyboard3_L2/M2.jpg?sigh=P7NmG8s8tqb0S2vdQXgI3EGK4ws) is what I'm looking to make. Long story short, this is how youtube generates their hover-preview thing, and I want to replicate that.

I have a nodejs script that can take a number of thumbnails from a video and store them to disk. It's also simple to [take some images on disk and combine them into a single image](https://superuser.com/questions/316132/appending-images-horizontally-in-imagemagick). However, I'd like to optimize this process by not having to store any images to disk until all the images are joined in the final reel.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a image every XX seconds of the video \[FFMPEG\]](http://superuser.com/questions/984686/create-a-image-every-xx-seconds-of-the-video-ffmpeg)

Comment: You could also take a look at http://superuser.com/a/726149/74576